# Why doesn't this piece of code replace the first letter of each word?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reference, pass-by-reference

I was trying to replace the first letter of each word and came up with this piece of code. Does anyone know why it doesn't work?

```
name = 'EFEIN DOED'
name.split(' ').map(b => {
   b = b.toLowerCase();
   console.log(b);
   b[0] = 3;
   console.log(b);
   return b;
}).join(' ');
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: b[0] = 3 - strings are immutable, you cannot write to an index.

Comment: @AlexK. You're right, thank you. That's all folks.

Comment: `name.replace(/(^|\s)\w/g, "$1"+3)` can also be used instead of `split, map and than join`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general idea is correct except that strings are immutable and therefore cannot be edited in that way. Here is an alternative that returns `'3fein 3oed'`:

```
name.split(' ').map(b => '3' + b.toLowerCase().substring(1)).join(' ');
```

Comment: `name.replace(/(^|\s)\w/g, "$1"+3)` can also be used instead of `split, map and than join`

Comment: you will also need to assign it to a new variable to use it as 'name' variable is immutable (as stated above). ```const newName = name.split(' ').map(b => '3' + b.toLowerCase().substring(1)).join(' ');```